# Flexbox behaviour when mixing div with other elements

Tags: html, flexbox

In following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
a:link {color:rgba(0,0,0,1); background-color:rgba(160,15,15,1); text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color:rgba(0,0,0,1); background-color:rgba(160,15,15,1); textdecoration:none;}
a:hover {color:rgba(255,27,24,1); background-color:rgba(138,75,65,1); textdecoration:none;}
a:active {color:rgba(150,228,0,1); background-color:rgba(110,60,0,1);textdecoration:none;}


a { border:2px solid rgba(120,3,3,1);border-radius:10%;padding:2px;font-color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;">
<a href="">Link1</a>
<div><a href="">Link2</a></div>
<div><a href="">Link3</a></div>
<span><a href="">Link4</a></span>
<a href="">Link5</a>
<a href="">Link6</a>
<a href="">Link7</a>
<a href="">Link8</a>
</div>
<p>
Test Test Test
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the `div` and `span` embedded elements change alignment? Initially I thought it was because `div` has different properties that just a link (link is an inline element, whereas divs are block). But embedding in a `span` (an inline element) instead of a `div` has the same effect.

Anyone ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Element in there is changing alignment.

If you would go into Chrome or any other browser that has Devtool and check the height of those divs and compare them to the other `<a>` you will see them of equal height, However since you're not assigning a border or a background you don't really see what's happening, so let's try that.

```css
body>div>* {
  background: lime;
}

a {
  border: 2px solid rgba(120, 3, 3, 1);
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding: 2px;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;">
  <a href="">Link1</a>
  <div><a href="">Link2</a></div>
  <div><a href="">Link3</a></div>
  <span><a href="">Link4</a></span>
  <a href="">Link5</a>
  <a href="">Link6</a>
  <a href="">Link7</a>
  <a href="">Link8</a>
</div>
```

As you can see all direct children has equal height, that's what flex do, However why the a inside the divs and the span are up a bit, well that is due to how inline level elements display, Inline level elements display like text, so the way it behaves is very different than a block, but that space below there, is kept for [Descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). Also setting a border like you're doing will get out of the parents boundaries but only from the top and bottom, padding behaves in the same way, you can see it grow from the top and bottom but that won't have an effect on the surrounding elements, will effect them only from the right and left, these are just a few of differences between inline and block level elements.

Easy fix set your `<a>` to `inline-block`, will still treat them as inline level elements when it comes to how much space they need, but it will give their block so it affects the surrounding elements on all sides.